# Connecting a XML-element to a Class property in C# using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am learning c#! I wonder if there is a way to define a Class property which represents a XML-element and how it is possible to read the property from a XML file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have such Xml File:

```
<Root>
<ExampleTag1>Hello from Minsk.</ExampleTag1>
<ExampleTag2>Hello from Moskow.</ExampleTag2>
...
</Root>
```

You can create something like this:

```
public class Class1 : IDisposable
    {
        private string filePath;
        private XDocument document;

        public Class1(string xmlFilePath)
        {
            this.filePath = xmlFilePath;
            document = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
        }

        public XElement ExampleTag1
        {
            get
            {
                return document.Root.Element("ExampleTag1");
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            document.Save(filePath);
        }
    }
```

And then use it:

```
new Class1(filePath).ExampleTag1.Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you can certainly declare a property of type `XElement`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public XElement Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And you can read it from an XML file using code like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = doc.Root; // The root element of the file...
```

Obviously you can get at other elements, e.g.

```
foo.Bar = doc.Descendants("SomeElementName").First();
```

... but without a more specific question, it's hard to give a more specific answer.